# In Java MongoDb how can I save the values of a specific field in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, mongodb

Suppose we have the following documents:

```
  {{i:1},{i:9},{i:10}}
  {i:3}
  {{i:4},{i:0}}
  {{i:5},{i:-3},{i:30}}
```

each line represents a document

is it possible to save the values of i in an ArrayList or some kind of List in general?

I'm trying to achieve this in java

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alter your documents slightly as follows:

```
{ivalues:[{i:1},{i:9},{i:10}]}
```

Then you should be able to create the document in Java as follows:

```
ArrayList<DBObject> x = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
x.add(new BasicDBObject("i", 1));
x.add(new BasicDBObject("i", 9));
x.add(new BasicDBObject("i", 10));
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("ivalues", x);
```

And save/retrieve it as normal.